# Numeric inputs without spinners?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want the user to input a number like `64.32`, and two-way-bind this to a property of type `number`.

I tried

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="size">
```

but this shows a spinner, which is pretty useless for entering a fractional number of this magnitude, and takes up space that could be used better.

I also tried

```
<input [(ngModel)]="size">
```

but this puts a `string` into the model property rather than a `number`.

Currently I am converting between `string` and `number` in a setter/getter, but surely there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use CSS to achieve that.

```
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```